# What are the thoughs of a blind and deaf person?

Tags: theory-of-mind, thought

I've always asked myself of what are made the thoughs of a blind and deaf person... Are they made of concepts? Sensations? Ideas? Have we ever asked a blind and deaf person about that?

Comment: Related question: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10579/7001 - from my answer: "Deaf people often report thinking visually - in sign, print, or lip-reading for example. Blind people to some degree, and deafblind people to a greater degree report some tactile thinking - presumably if they use braille or a tactile sign language."

Comment: Also related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17128/7001